# Android how to get a int return from a method

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Maybe this is a "simple" question but I have this method:

```
public int getMaxColumnData() {
    bdd = maBaseSQLite.getWritableDatabase();
    final SQLiteStatement stmt = bdd
                .compileStatement("SELECT MAX(column) FROM Table");
    return (int) stmt.simpleQueryForLong();
}
```

and I would like to do this `int i = getMaxColumnData();`

And that throws an error.

My goal is to find the maximum of a column in the database table.

Here is the error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getMaxColumnData() from the type CapteursBDD

Comment: It's helpful to include the error you actually get.

Comment: It is done. I changed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: the problem is probably because `bdd` is declared as `static` whereas the method in which you use `bdd` is not static.

Changing the method signature to `public static int getMaxColumnData()` might solve your problem.

Comment: Thenk you for your answer @jcxavier
Can you please give me more details abaut this?
I would like to find the max number of a culumn im my table.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

change method signature to `public static int getMaxColumnData() {....}` and try. Need to change the method as static method.